# C++ Eigen: why can one add-assign but not add for the method asDiagonal()

Tags: c++, eigen

I've noticed some unexpected behaviour in Eigen:

```
int n=10;  //value is irrelevant 
Eigen::MatrixXd A(n);
Eigen::VectorXd v(n);

//works:
Eigen::MatrixXd B = A;
B += v.asDiagonal();

//error:
Eigen::MatrixXd C = A + v.asDiagonal();
```

In the second case, the compiler complains that there is no suitable `operator+` availaible taking a `MatrixXd` and a `DiagonalWrapper<...>`. (The same holds for other operators as well).

Is this intended? And if yes, is there a neat way around the two-line alternative (first assign, then subtract)?

Comment: Looks like a pending issue related to this bug: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=610

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that seems to be the expected behaviour (probably due to optimisation reasons, but it's just a guess). You can, however, do the following:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd C = A + v.asDiagonal().toDenseMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write an operator+ yourself, e.g.

```
namespace Eigen {
  template <typename OtherMatrix>
  auto operator+(MatrixXd lhs, OtherMatrix&& rhs)
  {
    return lhs += rhs;
  }
}
```

Note that this will force evaluation of the `lhs` argument, specifically anything that can value construct a `MatrixXd` will be accepted, which may be why the Eigen writers have omitted it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's really a bad approach. One reason; it will  shadow all other `+`-operations.